# Type safety: Unchecked cast leads to java.lang.ClassCastException

Tags: java

I'm getting the error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: Group cannot be cast to Person
```

due to

```
Type safety: Unchecked cast from List<capture#1-of ?> to List<Person>
```

from the code:

```
List<Person> arrangedPerson = PersonAddImportHelper.setChannelInfo(
                (List<Person>) (List<?>) group.getRecipients(), model);
at ui.PersonAddImportHelper.setChannelInfo(PersonAddImportHelper.java:42)
at ui.GroupMembersController.viewGroupMembers(GroupMembersController.java:170)
```

from `GroupMembersController.viewGroupMembers (GroupMembersController.java:170)`

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/list/{id}/{page}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String viewGroupMembers(@PathVariable("id") final Group group,
            @PathVariable("page") final int page,
            @RequestParam(value = "pageSize", defaultValue = DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE) final int pageSize,
            @RequestParam(value = "search", defaultValue = "") final String search,
            @RequestParam(value = "sortColumn", defaultValue = "lastname") final String sortColumn,
            @RequestParam(value = "filter", defaultValue = "") final String filter,
            final Model model) {
        List<Person> arrangedPerson = PersonAddImportHelper.setChannelInfo(
                (List<Person>) (List<?>) group.getRecipients(), model);
        for (Person person : arrangedPerson) {
            group.addMember(person);
        }
        list(group, page, Integer.valueOf(pageSize), search, sortColumn, filter, model);
        model.addAttribute("group", group);
        return "/recipient/groupPersonList";
    }
```

And `ui.PersonAddImportHelper.setChannelInfo` is:

```
public static List<Person> setChannelInfo(final List<Person> items,
            final Model model) {
        List<Person> arrangedPerson = new ArrayList<>();
        final Map<Person, Boolean> hasEmail = Maps
                .newHashMapWithExpectedSize(items.size());
        final Map<Person, Boolean> hasFixed = Maps
                .newHashMapWithExpectedSize(items.size());
        final Map<Person, Boolean> hasMobile = Maps
                .newHashMapWithExpectedSize(items.size());
        for (Person person : items) {
            List<Address> addresses = ((Person) person).getAddresses();
            List<Address> arrangedAddresses = new ArrayList<Address>(
                    Arrays.asList(new Address[ADDRESS_MAX_SIZE]));
            int mobileIndex = 0;
            int fixedIndex = 2;
            int emailIndex = ADDRESS_PHONE_START_INDX;
            for (Address address : addresses) {
                // some Logic
            }
            ((Person) person).setAddresses(arrangedAddresses);
            arrangedPerson.add(person);
        }
        model.addAttribute("hasEmail", hasEmail);
        model.addAttribute("hasFixed", hasFixed);
        model.addAttribute("hasMobile", hasMobile);
        return arrangedPerson;
    }
```

Comment: what is this for? `(List<Person>) (List<?>) group.getRecipients()` ?

Comment: what is `group.getRecipients()` return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to provide the inheritance hierarchy. From the error you are getting, I deduce that `group.getRecipients()` returns a list containing items that are not `Person`. I think that's also the reason for the double cast `(List<Person>) (List<?>) group.getRecipients()`, because the compiler won't accept the direct cast `(List<Person>) group.getRecipients()`.

Your workaround to make the compiler accept your code just pushed the error from compile time to runtime, and it will be triggered when `for (Person person : items)` is reached.

Change the return type of `group.getRecipients()` to `List<Person>` or let `Group` inherit from `Person`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very strange pice of code:

`(List<Person>) (List<?>) group.getRecipients()`

What does `getRecipients()` return? And why are you casting twice? Seems that group.getRecipients() returns something else than List?

Comment: When casting a generic type, you need to cast twice, because Java do not allow to cast `Generic<Foo>` directly to `Generic<Bar>`.

Answer (score 1):

what i see from the code

```
 (List<Person>) (List<?>) group.getRecipients()
```

that you are trying to cast Group to your Person class which what the error even shows..